# Problema em chamada de action via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estou criando um submit form através do meu javascript e enviando um objeto para ser consumido pela minha Action na Controller.
Já tentei de varias formas e mesmo assim não acontece da forma como esperado.
nesse código abaixo esta retornando erro 400.

JS

```
var valor = {"IdContato":0,"IdUsuario":0,"Nome":descricao,"Telefone":"","Email":"","Status":"","Corretor":"","Captador":"","Pessoa":"","IdPessoa":"","TipoContato":"","IdTipoContato":"","Genero":"","IdGenero":""};
var url = "/Contato/Inicio/";

post(url, valor);

function post(path, params, method = "POST") {      
      const form = document.createElement('form');
      form.method = method;      
      form.action = path;
      form.style = "style: none";
      for (const key in params) {
         if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
            hiddenField.name = key;
            hiddenField.value = params[key];

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
      }
      document.body.appendChild(form);
      form.submit();
   }
```

Minha Controller

```
[HttpPost("Contato/Inicio")]
      public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ContatoFilterDto filter)
      {
         await carregaDropDowns();
         var usuarioLogado = GetUsuarioLogado();
         filter.IdUsuario = usuarioLogado.Id;
         var result = await _contatoApplication.GetByFilter(filter);
         ViewBag.Contatos = result;
         return View();
      }
```

A intenção deses código é após a execução da controller, chamar a view de contatos com os dados filtrados.
Mas como mencionei, ao chamar o código acima, o browser indica erro 400, como se a pagina não existe.

Esse aqui é meu html. se trata de um navBar com um Select onde de acordo com a chave ele envia para uma pagina de pesquisa.
O que eu fiz no javascript, foi transformar o valor do input do select em um form e enviar via post pelo submit.

HMTL

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@{

    var title = ViewData["Title"];
    UsuarioViewModel user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsuarioViewModel>(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Usuario").Value);
    var userId = user != null ? user.Id : 0;
    var webAppUrl = ViewBag.WebAppUrl;
    string imagemPerfil = user != null && user?.PossuiImagemPerfil == true ? $"{webAppUrl}/{user.CaminhoImagemPerfil}" : $"{webAppUrl}/images/profile-picture.jpg";
}

<style>
    .nav-link-icon {
        font-size: 35px;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        line-height: 38px;
    }
    .dropdown-optgroup {
        padding: 0 8px;
        font-size: .9em;
    }
</style>

<nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button" style="padding-right: 15px;"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="input-group">
                @*<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Ref. Imóvel</button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><span class="dropdown-optgroup">Contatos</span></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nome</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">E-mail</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Telefone</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CPF/CNPJ</a></li>
                   <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                   <li><span class="dropdown-optgroup">Imóvel</span></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Titulo do Imóvel</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Código do Imóvel</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Proprietário</a></li>
                   <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                   <li><span class="dropdown-optgroup">Leads</span></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nome</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">E-mail</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Telefone</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Código do Imóvel</a></li>
                </ul>*@
               <select class="form-select btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" id="slctBuscar" style="text-align:left"  aria-label="Default select example">
                  <optgroup label="Contatos">
                     <option value="1">Nome</option>
                     <option value="2">E-mail</option>
                     <option value="3">Telefone</option>
                     <option value="4">CPF/CNP</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="Imóvel">
                     <option value="5">Titulo do Imóvel</option>
                     <option value="6">Código do Imóvel</option>
                     <option value="7">Proprietário</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="Leads">
                     <option value="8">Nome</option>
                     <option value="9">E-mail</option>
                     <option value="10">Telefone</option>
                     <option value="11">Código do Imóvel</option>
                  </optgroup>                   
               </select>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBuscar" aria-label="Pesquisa Ref. Imóvel">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" id="btnBuscar">Pesquisar</button>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" style="padding-left: 15px;"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-left">
               <a asp-controller="Contato" asp-action="Registro" class="dropdown-item">
                  Cliente
               </a>
               <a asp-controller="Imovel" asp-action="Registro" class="dropdown-item">
                  Imóvel
               </a>
               <a asp-controller="Agendamento" asp-action="Registro" class="dropdown-item">
                  Agenda
               </a>
               <a asp-controller="Atendimento" asp-action="Registro" class="dropdown-item">
                  Atendimento
               </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="gap: 5px;">

        <li class="nav-item">
           <button type="button" id="btnContract" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Usuario", new { id = @userId })'+'#assinaturas'" class="btn btn-success">             
                 <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
                 Contratar
           </button>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i>
                Ver Site
            </button>
        </li>

        @*<li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
                <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge">15</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
                <span class="dropdown-header">15 Notifications</span>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i> 4 new messages
                    <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">3 mins</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-users mr-2"></i> 8 friend requests
                    <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">12 hours</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-file mr-2"></i> 3 new reports
                    <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">2 days</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Notifications</a>
            </div>
        </li>*@

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="padding: 3px 10px;">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="@imagemPerfil" class="img-circle elevation-2 img-profile" alt="User Image">
                </div>
            </a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
                <a asp-controller="Usuario" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@userId" class="dropdown-item">
                    Configurações
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Conta" asp-action="LogOut">
                    Sair
                </a>
            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>

<script>
   var ObjetoConsulta = new Object();
   function pegarUrl(value) {
      switch (value) {
         case '1':
         case '2':
         case '3':
         case '4':
            return "/api/PesquisarContato";
            break;
         case '5':
         case '6':
         case '7':
            return "/api/PesquisarImovel";
            break;
         case '8':
         case '9':
         case '10':
         case '11':
            return "/api/PesquisarLeads";
            break;
         default:            
      }
   }
   ObjetoConsulta.Buscar = function (url, value, descricao) {                  
      console.log(url);
      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: url,
         dataType: "JSON",
         cache: false,
         async: true,
         data: { value: value, descricao: descricao },
         success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = "/Contato/Inicio/";
            var hiddenField = document.getElementsByName('input');
            hiddenField.setAttribute('value', descricao);
            console.log(descricao);
         }
      });
   }
   $(function () {
      $("#btnBuscar").click(
         function () {
            var value = $("#slctBuscar").val();
            var descricao = $("#inputBuscar").val();
            var url = pegarUrl(value);
            ObjetoConsulta.Buscar(url, value, descricao);            
                    
         });
   });
</script>
```

Classe ContatoFilterDto

```
using ProCorretor.Domain.Enumerators;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ProCorretor.Domain.DTOs.Filters
{
    public class ContatoFilterDto
    {
        public int? IdContato { get; set; }
        public int? IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Corretor { get; set; }
        public string Captador { get; set; }
        public int Pessoa { get; set; }
        public Pessoa IdPessoa { get; set; }
        public int TipoContato { get; set; }
        public TipoContato IdTipoContato { get; set; }
        public int Genero { get; set; }
        public Genero IdGenero { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: 400 é *bad request* o que é direrente de um 404, *"como se a pagina não exitisse"* como você mencionou. O 400 pode acontecer por a requisição foi mal feita e não pode ser recebida nesse caso na action. Possíveis razões: - verbot errado (espera POST recebeu um GET), o objeto não é o esperado (esperar um Date e veio um int, etc), *header* inválido, etc. Isso era pra contextualizar, agora pra saber melhor falta ai no seu código o html por exemplo (está fazendo posto via form, falta a tag form), falta a definição da classe `ContatoFilterDto`, pra ver se faz match com o json

Comment: Pra um melhor debug sugiro ir na ferramente de debug do brower (F12) e ver lá na aba de rede (network) o que foi enviado e qual o erro, lá deve mostrar o problema, que pode ser a url, o tipo de chamada e também o objeto que foi enviado. Adicione esses dados na pergunta para te ajudarmos melhor :)

Comment: Efetuei a edição com o HMTL e a Classe.

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente o que está acontecendo é que no teu endpoint, você espera receber um objeto com as propriedades IdContato, IdUsuario, Nome, etc...

Mas o que você está enviando do front são somente essas propriedades "soltas".

Você teria a principio, duas soluções:

1. **Mandar um objeto para o endpoint, por exemplo:**

```
valor = { 
    "objeto":{
        "IdContato":0,
        "IdUsuario":0,
        "Nome":"descricao",
        "Telefone":"",
        "Email":"",
        "Status":"",
        "Corretor":"",
        "Captador":"",
        "Pessoa":"",
        "IdPessoa":"",
        "TipoContato":"",
        "IdTipoContato":"",
        "Genero":"",
        "IdGenero":""
    }
};
```

2. **Poderia também, adaptar teu endpoint, para receber esses dados
   separados:**

```
[HttpPost("Contato/Inicio")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int idContato, int idUsuario, string nome, etc....)
{
    var filter  = new ContatoFilterDto()
    {
        IdUsuario = idUsuario,
        Nome = nome
        ....
    };

    await carregaDropDowns();
    var usuarioLogado = GetUsuarioLogado();
    filter.IdContato = usuarioLogado.Id;
    var result = await _contatoApplication.GetByFilter(filter);
    ViewBag.Contatos = result;
    return View();
}
```

Essa segunda solução ficaria melhor usando AutoMapper por exemplo, eu particularmente acho mais correto a primeira abordagem.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema mencionado.
O que acontece é que mesmo enviando do Metodo "POST", ele enviava para o GET.
Alterei o endpoint para GET e a rotina executou corretamente, o próprio framework se encarrega de transformar o objeto Json em uma classe, basta enviar a propriedades iguais.

Encontrei em uma documentação que a chamada que eu estava executando, não aceita POST, por isso do problema.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).